# Sefira Counting in Diaspora

Tags: chutz-laaretz, sefirat-ha-omer

Why don't we count two nights each night, if there was always a Safek (doubt) what the date is.

In other words: if we are not sure when the second night of Pesach is, why don't we carry that doubt throughout the entire duration of Sefira?

Comment: related: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/second-day-of-shavous

Comment: Is there any example of Sefeika DeYoma on a Derabanan? (Not counting like Melakha with a Shinui which is part of an overall Deorayta that needs to be repeated so we repeat it in full.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Firstly, your question assumes that Sefira counting is Derabanan which is itself a point of contention. Second, if the Rabanan say to do X on Y day(s) of the year, and we don't know when Rosh Chodesh is, when do you do it?

Comment: @yydl that's real sefeka deyoma. I'm asking if we find anywhere that after the fixed calendar we still do double on a Derabanan. I can't think of anywhere, but every Deorayta has it.

Answer (score 16):

> From Nefesh HaRav by Rabbi Herschel
>   Schachter, shlita,:
>
> "The Rishonim [end of Tractate
>   Pesachim] ask the following: 'Why
>   don't we count Sefirat HaOmer each
>   night twice [i.e., "today is the
>   second day," and "today is the first
>   day," etc.] due to the doubtful day?'
>
> "HaRav Joseph B. Soloveitchik, zt"l,
>   heard a reason why we do not do so
>   from the Kovno Rav [see Devar
>   Avraham]: If a person counts twice due
>   to doubt, i.e., stating that it is
>   either the fourth day of the Omer or
>   the fifth day of the Omer, he will not
>   have fulfilled his mitzva at all
>   because a doubtful count is not
>   considered a count. Our Sages stated
>   in the first perek of Bava Metzia
>   regarding ma'aser behema that it must
>   be the tenth of every ten animals, and
>   not a doubtful tenth."
>
> In conclusion, now that we have an
>   established calendar and our
>   celebration of two days Yom Tov is
>   only due to the minhag of our fathers,
>   as noted in the beginning of Tractate
>   Beitza, we count consecutive numbers
>   each night, starting from the second
>   night of Pesach until we have counted
>   seven complete weeks - to Shavuot

[Q & A: Sefirat HaOmer – When To Start Counting (Part III)](http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/ask-the-rabbi/q-a-sefirat-haomer-when-to-start-counting-part-iii/2014/04/14/2/)

Answer (score 3):

*Taame Haminhagim* 577 answers (in my own loose translation):

> … because we shouldn't be so strict about it, since it's nothing but a remembrance to what was done when we had the *bes hamikdash*.
>
> Another [reason] is that if we count one day ahead then we'll reach number 49 on *Shavuos*, which we'll therefore come to treat lightly. (*Avudraham*.)

He then offers a reason of his own. I'll quote it, but I don't understand it:

> If we count twice in one day, then one will need to count "today is the second day" on the third day, and, in case the first day is the true [first day], he'll need to count "today is the third day" with a blessing on the third day. And likewise for every day.

Comment: I don't see why 49 on the Yom Tov of Shavuot is worse than 1 on the Yom Tov of Pesach.

Comment: @DoubleAA, nor I, but I guess the _Avudraham_ does. `:-)` Maybe 49 on the _yom tov mid'oray'sa_ is worse than 1 on the _yom tov mid'rabanan_.

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps because the very essence of Shavuos is that it comes after 49 days of the omer.

Comment: The first answer assumes it's a derabannan today, and doesn't help those who hold it's doraisa

Answer (score -4):

We also do not say Ushpizin twice each night on Succos. This would seem to indicate that although we have Sefeika DeYoma we do not extend it to either the Omer or the Ushpizin.

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this only indicate that we do not extend the concept of Sefeika deYoma to Ushpizin? How does this indicate if we do or do not extend Sefeika deYoma to Omer?