# Last night *might* have been the first night of the omer. Right?

Tags: passover, calendar, sefirat-ha-omer, safek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sefira Counting in Diaspora](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6964/sefira-counting-in-diaspora)

How do we count sefira with absolute certainty, as we do, and yet, in diaspora, we have a second seder and a second day of yom tov? Wouldn't the lack of certainty imply that we don't know which night of sefira it is? If so, why don't we count twice every night? Or hold only one day of yom tov?

Answer (score 1):

We know with certainty, ever since the fixed calendar was established; *yom tov sheni* is kept because of tradition, not uncertainty.

Comment: What about back in the day?

Comment: @BaalShemotTovot Synopsis of my comment in the linked question - Chances are that since messengers arrived in the middle of the Omer announcing when Rosh Hodesh Nissan began, they would have discontinued double counting as the *safek* had then been removed.